# Does anyone know a way to get rid of sticky tooltips in Domino Designer 9.0 w/o restarting the application?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I don't know if it is just me, but I have an issue with tooltips sticking on my screen.  These tooltips were activated by hovering in Domino Designer 9.0.   The problem is that they don't go away, not everytime, but far too often.  I can't figure out how to make them go away short of restarting designer.   This is really annoying.  See the example of the stuck tooltip still visible in Chrome while typing in this question.

BTW, I have 8GB ram, and already optimized my memory per instuctions in the Matt White/Tim Clark presentation.

Am I alone here?  Has anyone figured out a workaround?

[image: Stuck tooltip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was just me as I use Designer through RDP (ah the joys of having a Mac.) Some of the times I can hit Esc and it will remove the dialog. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I tried that, but not 100% sure.  I will try that the next time it happens.  It seems to be happening more and more for me.  I am guessing that this is bug in 9.0.  We are probably due for a 9.0.1 soon.  I don't remember this happening in 8.5.3.

Comment: If I remember correctly there was a problem with focus, this seems to be something that N9 has some problems with. I think I needed to give the correct area focus before hitting ESC. You are not alone, but I do remember having these problems with 853, but again I am using RDP to connect and that does introduce some other problems.

Comment: Now that I want it to happen to test it, it is not doing it.  It may have happened in 8.5.3 and I just don't remember, we were early adopters of 9.0.   Btw: I am use windows 7.

Comment: Same, Windows7. As I tell my users when the problem goes away, "You can't argue with results" lol

Comment: Funny, whenever it happens again I will try 'escape' and remember to update this SO.

Comment: Well, it finally happened again, and you are right Escape does work, as long as you are in Designer.   That was simple, thanks.